# Embedded MongoDB Chart filtered by ObjectId is not displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to display a chart from MongoDB Charts in my React Native app, ussing an iFrame. The graph shows Tasks that belong to a user and I want to filter them by the id of the user.

The filter settings in Mongodb Charts are configured.

It always returns me a blank chart. If I remove the filter or filter for another field, it is seen without problem.

This is the url with the filter:

```
`https://charts.mongodb.com/charts-mitiempo-trqxx/embed/charts?id=88615f15-7209-4048-a1f0-e8944d467c26&filter={"userId":%20{$eq:%20ObjectId('60b668e3a882060015dd4747')}}&theme=light`
```

A detail of the filter:

```
&filter={"userId":%20{$eq:%20ObjectId('60b668e3a882060015dd4747')}}&theme=light`
```

I think it's something from the filter's URI encoding or a syntax error, but I can't find the what... Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs help with this, the solution was to use $ oid instead of ObjectId ():

```
filter={"userId":%20{'$oid':%20'${state._id}'}}
```